# Adding dropdown list on a cell

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown list on each cell of table row. Now what I need is dynamically add more dropdownlist on a particular cells with pressing the add button. Any code snippet to help on this? Thank you.
Below is the codes. I have tried function addSubRow2 but this is very static and I cant move further because beside each combo box I also need a text box and how give each of them an unique id so that later I can identify during validation and submission into php page?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
                newcell.innerHTML = newcell.innerHTML +"<br> TEST";
                //alert(newcell.childNodes[2].type);
                /*switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            newcell.childNodes[0].id = "input" + rowCount;
                            break;
                    case "checkbox":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                            newcell.childNodes[0].id = "checkbox" + rowCount;     
                            break;
                    case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[1].selectedIndex = 0;
                        newcell.childNodes[1].id = "col_" + rowCount+"_2"; 
                            break;
                }*/
                /*if(newcell.childNodes[0].type=="button")
                {
                    alert("TEST");
                    newcell.childNodes[0].id=rowCount;
                }*/
            }

            /*var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
                  row.id="row"+i;
                  row.name="row"+i;
                  var rowName = "row"+i;
               //iterate through rows
               //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
               for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                 //iterate through columns
                 //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
                 col.id="col_"+i+"_"+j;
                   col.name="col_"+i+"_"+j;
                 var cels = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[j];
                 var realKids = 0,count = 0;
                 kids = cels.childNodes.length;
                 while(count < kids){
                        if(cels.childNodes[i].nodeType != 3){
                            realKids++;
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                    ///alert("I : "+i+"   "+"J : "+j+"  "+"realKids :"+cels.childElementCount);
                //alert();
          for(var k=0 ; k<cels.childElementCount ; k++)
          {

            alert("J :"+j+"  "+"K :"+k+"  "+cels.childNodes[k].type);
          }
               }  
            }*/
        }

        function addSubRow2(cell){
            var dropdown = "<SELECT class=\"select\" name=\"country\">\n" +
            "<OPTION value=\"1\">Serial 1<\/OPTION>\n" +
            "<OPTION value=\"2\">Serial 2<\/OPTION>\n" +
            "<OPTION value=\"3\">Serial 3<\/OPTION>\n" + 
            "<OPTION value=\"4\">Serial 4<\/OPTION>" +
            "<OPTION value=\"5\">Serial 5<\/OPTION>" + 
            "<\/SELECT>";
        //var dropdown =  document.getElementById("dataTable").rows[0].cells[2].childNodes[1].cloneNode(true);
        cell.innerHTML += "<br\/ >" + dropdown;
    }


/*alert("COLD ID : "+colID);
            var tdID = document.getElementById(colID);
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var new_comboBox = table.rows[0].cells[2].childNodes[2].cloneNode(true);


    tdID.appendChild(new_comboBox);*/


        function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    if(rowCount <= 1) {
                        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                        break;
                    }
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }


            }
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
                  row.id="row"+i;
               //iterate through rows
               //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
               for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                 //iterate through columns
                 //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
                 //alert("J : "+j);
                 col.id="col"+i;
                 if(j==0)
                 {

                 }
                 else if(j==1)
                 {

                }
               }  
            }

            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
  Begin Location : <select class='select' id="beginLocation" name="beginLocation">
                    <option value="1">Loc 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Loc 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Loc 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Loc 4</option>
                    <option value="5">Loc 5</option>
                </select>
                <p type="text" class=error id='beginLocation_Error'>
    <br\>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

    <table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Client</th>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th>Serial</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="col_0_0"><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
            <td id="col_0_1">
                <select class='select' id="client1" name="client1">
                    <option value="1">Client 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Client 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Client 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Client 4</option>
                    <option value="5">Client 5</option>
                </select><p type="text" class=error id='client_0_Error'>                
            </td>

            <td id="col_0_1">
                <select class='select' id="location1" name="location1">
                  <option value="1">Loc 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Loc 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Loc 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Loc 4</option>
                    <option value="5">Loc 5</option>
                </select>
                <p type="text" class=error id='beginLocation_Error'>                
            </td>

            <td id="col_0_3">
                <input type="button" value="Add Serial" onclick="addSubRow2(this.parentNode);" />
                <br\>
                <select class='select' id="serial_0_1" name="serial_0_1">
                    <option value="1">Serial 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Serial 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Serial 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Serial 4</option>
                    <option value="5">Serial 5</option>
                </select><input type="text" name=txtLoc" id="txtLoc><p type="text" class=error id='serial_0_1_Error'>


            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @clybe I have updated the codes which I have tried so far

Comment: find a code snippet here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ex_dom.asp?output=print

Comment: how to duplicate  the original combo box and also a text box beside and also <p> to later show the error message. Finally I need to validate and also capture the values in php page?

Comment: @ClydeLobo anymore details you need ?

Comment: no, I think you have a good answer by Zoltan

Comment: @ClydeLobo how do I control the id as each time a new combo is added I need an id which combination of both row and colum right? Is it possible to have a remove button to remove the added combo box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5wVnR/)

***JS***

```
var i = 0;
var option;

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", addSelect, false);

function addSelect() {
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    select.setAttribute("name", "mySelect" + i);
    select.setAttribute("id", "mySelect" + i);

    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", "value one");
    option.innerHTML = "ONE";
    select.appendChild(option);

    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", "value two");
    option.innerHTML = "TWO";
    select.appendChild(option);

    document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(select);

    i++;
}
```

Comment: I have added my code is there any help on how to proceed from my codes with the unique id so that I can validate and easier for php processing too?

Comment: I need it to copy the original combo box and keep adding but how during validation to validate that each of the serial combo is selected and to identify their value in php page?